# Limpiar filas con emails inválidos de una hoja de cálculo de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Pues llevo bastante peleándome con este asunto, ya que, si no fuera porque la función tiene que hacer muchas cosas más, tardaría menos haciéndolo con filtros a mano...

La cosa es que quiero eliminar de un Google Sheet todas las filas cuya celda de email sean inválidos o de Gmail.

Al principio lo hice con una macro que me dio el siguiente código:

```
function Limpiarfilasycolumnas() {

  //Seleccionar hoja y empezar
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();


  //No funciona
  //Localizar y eliminar todo lo que no sea un email
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=NOT(REGEXMATCH(E:E;"^([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"))')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,1,spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();

  //No funciona
  //Localizar y borrar los emails de Gmail
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextContains('gmail.com')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,1,spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();


};
```

Pero haciendo pruebas me percaté de que si la hoja era distinta, ya no funcionaba la macro... Así que después de leerme todas las preguntas con título relacionado, me decanté por hacerlo por Javascript como comentaba el usuario Rubén en una de sus respuestas.

Así que, he hecho el código simulando el filtro con Javascript y me ha quedado lo siguiente:

```
function Pruebas() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  limpia_columna_email(ss.getActiveSheet());
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Hoja actualizada correctamente");
};

function limpia_columna_email(ss)
{
  var emails = ss.getRange("E:E").getValues();
  for(var i = emails.length-1; i > 0 ; i--)
  {
    if(!validar_mail(emails[i][0])) ss.deleteRow(i+1);
  }
};

function validar_mail(email)
{
  var patron = new RegExp("^([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
  if(email == null || email == "") return false;
  if(email.search("gmail.com") != -1) return false;
  return patron.test(email);
  return false; //Aquí no debe de llegar nunca
};
```

Ahora bien, la hoja que le paso tiene más de 5000 filas... y ejecutar el código ha tardado una barbaridad (vamos, si me descuido me veo el capítulo de Stranger Things entero...).

Más que optimizar, que también sería bienvenido ¿qué es lo que está causando que tarde tanto?

Comment: Bienvenido. Primero, felicidades por incluir en tu primera pregunta los esfuerzos de buscar/investigar/intentar. Recomendaciones 1. si tu pregunta es larga, incluye un resumen al inicio, o bien empieza con una pregunta muy específica, 2. Evita enunciados como "se os ocurre...." porque ese tipo de enunciados hace que tu pregunta se vea del tipo "principalmente basadas en opiniones" las cuales no se permiten en este sitio. 3. No se deben incluir saludos ni gracias. ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como regla de dedo siempre que sea posible debe evitarse o minimizarse el uso de métodos de los servicios de Google Apps Script en bucles (loops) porque usualmente estas llamadas son muy lentas. En este caso `deletRow` es particularmente lento y si tienes muchos emails inválidos pues he ahí la explicación.

Una solución es que te olvides del script y uses la función incluida de hoja de cálculo [ISEMAIL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256503?hl=es) en conjunto con las funciones de la interfaz, como ordenar, filtrar y eliminar filas. Con un poco de práctica en un santiamén depuraras tu lista.

Si persistes en la idea de usar scripts, si tu hoja sólo se usa para datos planos, es decir, no incluyes notas, comentarios, texto con formato, algo que ayudaría mucho es que en lugar de eliminar filas de la hoja de cálculo, use getDataRange y getValues para obtener un Array 2D con todos los valores de la hoja, luego borras el contenido de la hoja y pases el Array 2D depurado.

Par lo anterior, me parece que lo optimo sería usar `Array.prototype.filter`, por ejemplo:

```
var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var output = values.filter(function(row){
   return validar_mail(row[4]);
});
```

Otra de las cosas que podría incidir en que tu script tarde tanto es que esta iterando sobre **todas las filas** que tiene la hoja ya que estas usando una referencia abierta `E:E`. Si tu hoja tiene muchas más de las necesarias tu script está "perdiendo el tiempo". Eliminar las filas en blanco podría ayudar, si esto es significativo o no dependerá de tu hoja.

Comment: Hola Rubén,

Al final conseguí finalizar el proceso haciendo uso de Array.prototype.filter, desconocía la existencia de Array.prototype.

Gracias a esto, he pasado de ver un capitulo de una serie a poder levantarme a hacerme un café o algo así, jajaja, ahora es tiempo aceptable.

Como observación comentar que, al sacar los valores de un rango y los filtras, el array resultante es más pequeño (menos elementos), por lo que al intentar insertarlo me daba error, así que hice una función para que añadiera elementos vacíos sustituyendo los eliminados, con esto ya funcionaba.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que. En cuanto a agregar elementos vacíos, esa es una forma, otra, quizás mejor es usar usar length para conocer el tamaño de cada dimensión de tu Array 2D y usar eso para determinar el tamaño del intervalo de destino requerido :)